# Verb in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Traffic congestion wastes fuel, which in turn produces more carbon dioxide through the car exhausts and contributes to the greenhouse effect.

In this sentence, does the phrase 'in turn produces more carbon dioxide through the car' mention about the reason?
I cannot find the real verb in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

We could break down the sentence and maybe make it clearer like this:

> Traffic congestion wastes fuel.
>   This makes more carbon dioxide, by means of the car exhaust.
>   So it contributes to the greenhouse effect.

The verbs in the sentence are *wastes*, *produces*, and *contributes*.

I think the sentence is a little hard to understand because *exhausts* is **not** a verb in this context; it means "[the escape of used gas or vapor from an engine" or "the conduit through which used gases escape"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhaust).  So it's not "through the car", but through the *car exhaust*.

The sentence is not very clearly written.  I would not have written "produces more carbon dioxide through the car exhausts" but "produces more carbon dioxide in car exhaust", because "the car exhausts" is not very idiomatic.  There's no reason to say *the* car exhausts, because we're not talking about specific cars or specific exhausts, and there's not reason to say exhaust*s*, because we're talking about exhaust as a general phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Three verbs: wastes, produces, contributes

The writer is saying that traffic congestion produces more carbon dioxide (presumably because the engine is running for a longer period of time sitting in traffic).